# Long user upload procedure in Keycloak (REST)

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Asking for your help.
We start docker image stand-alone Keycloak in openshift.
We add new users using REST. But everything works very slowly. For 240000 users the uploads takes 24 hours.

1. Has anyone come across this?
2. How do you add and update users?

Our server: CPU 4 4 GB.
Our version of keyclock 7.3.1.GA.

The connection is constantly breaking and we are forced to send user packages

Comment: The REST interface isn't the fastest thing. And it probably takes you more than one REST request to fully create the user. REST is mainly slow due to the back and forth between layers. So I've successfully used several concurrent sessions to create users more quickly.

Comment: Regarding the broken connections: You'll have to investigate the WildFly and database log. It might be JVM memory, database connection pool etc. But overall: 240,000 users is asking for a bulk import interface. The REST interface isn't really suitable for that job. But I'm not aware of a dedicated bulk interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on key cloak, the following actions were performed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX in_user_entity_001
     ON user_entity USING GIST (lower (username) gist_trgm_ops);
```

Explanations:

The pg_trgm extension is included in the set of plugins supplied with PostgreSQL and is supported by PostgreSQL developers (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html).

The created index is matched to a specific long query.